# What is sample and feature

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm reading Scikit-learn and I can't understand sample and feature. (n_samples, n_features)
Can anybody describe those by example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[x[1,2,3,4], x2[1,2,2,3], x[2,3,2,1]]
The data above has 4 features.  We can gives those features labels with a header.  We'll just call them feature 1, feature 2, feature 3.  For the first entry, feature 1 has a value of 1 and feature 2 has a value of 2 and so on.

A sample, is a subset of data taken from your dataset.  x[1,2,3,4] is a single sample of the dataset.

Whatever you are trying to do with Scikit-learn wants to know how many features you have, my example has 4 features (or columns).

Comment: Thanks. In digits dataset, which is sample, feature and target?

Comment: x[1,2,3,4] would be a sample.  The columns, which for x[1,2,3,4] are 1, 2, 3, and 4 respectively, are all features. Can you be more specific in what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @EvanB Can we consider each rows as sample?

Answer (score 0):

Sample is typically the number of items that you are training on. In the digits dataset, the number of samples are the number of digits written by all the writers. Each digit can then be represented in various ways, for instance, as coordinates in the XYZ space, maybe the pressure level to write each of the digits, and so on. They are the features.